# How to flatten 'helper' classes with one-to-one relationship in EF core?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have an entity that represents a Company:

```
class Company {
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    ...
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
}
```

I want to refactor and introduce a new class `Location` that will hold *Address* and *City*. So that the refactored code should look like this:

```
class Company {
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    ...
    public Location Location { get; set; }
}
```

The thing is that EF requests `ID` property for `Location` and creates a table for it.
I want to flatten `Location` inside `Company` so that the SQL table will look the same as before refactoring.
`Location`, as I see it, isn't really an entity, it's more of a helper class used by `Company`.

How should I accomplish this?
Also, if you think that's a *bad* thing, please let me know why :)

Comment: Just a question about your title... what does this have to do with one-to-one relationships? You're not implying that one city can only have one company? Or is your city really just a free-form string, leading to companies in New York, NewYork and NYC without you ever finding out they are in the same place?

Comment: What are you asking for was called *Complex Type* in EF6 and is not supported on current EF Core last official release (v1.1.2). But if you can wait, the support is coming with v2 - see *Owned entity types* in [Announcing EF Core 2.0 Preview 2](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2017/06/28/announcing-ef-core-2-0-preview-2/).

Comment: oerkelens, I took this into consideration, thank you.
@IvanStoev I'll keep myself up to date, thanks

Answer (score 3):

I faced with the same problem. After a few hours I found solution.

Override for your DbContext method OnModelCreating:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Company>().OwnsOne(typeof(Location), "Location");
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}
```

So the main method here **OwnsOne**.
You will find more information [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/owned-entities)